# Laravel - Trying to create acocunt, signin and send activation email is throwing"Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

Originally, the process works great, but the user has to activate their account before they can log in

So I'm tweaking my signup process so the user can access the dashboard and soon as they have signed up and then an activation email is sent (so other parts of the app will stay inactive until they confirm it).

Here is the latest code

```
public function postSignup() {

    // Create account form validation
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'email'             => 'required|max:50|email|unique:users',
            'username'          => 'required|max:50|min:3|unique:users',
            'password'          => 'required|min:6',
            'password_again'    => 'required|same:password'
        )
    );

    // test if validation is working
    if ($validator->fails()) { // If validation fails

        return Redirect::route('signup') // redirect to new account page
            ->withErrors($validator) // Show the errors
            ->withInput(); // Show original form input

    } else {

        // get the inputs and put them in to varibles
        $email      = Input::get('email');
        $username   = Input::get('username');
        $password   = Input::get('password');

        // Generate an activation code
        $code       = str_random(60);

        // Create new user in database
        $user = User::create(array(
            'email' => $email,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => Hash::make($password),
            'code' => $code,
            'active' => 0
        ));

        // log the user into the app
        $user = Auth::attempt(array(
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password
        ));


        if($user) {

            // Send activation email
            Mail::send('app.register.emails.activate', array('link' => URL::route('account-activate', $code), 'username' => $username), function($message) use ($user) {
                $message->to($user->email, $user->username)->subject('Activate your account');
            });

            // When completed send the user to dashboard
            return Redirect::route('dashboard')
                ->with('global', 'Your account has been created, we have sent you an email to confirm'); // send a global confirmation message
        }

    }

}
```

It seems the following code

```
$user = Auth::attempt(array(
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password
));
```

Is clashing with

```
Mail::send('app.register.emails.activate', array('link' => URL::route('account-activate', $code), 'username' => $username), function($message) use ($user) {
    $message->to($user->email, $user->username)->subject('Activate your account');
});
```

I can either remove the Auth::attempt and the mail gets sent but I have to re-login or I remove the Mail::send and it signs me up and logs me in (without sending conformation email), but if I have both I get and error exception:

"Trying to get property of non-object"

Fairly new to PHP/Laravel so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already created and filled the `$user` variable when you run `User::create()`

You are then overwritting the `$user` with true/false when you run `Auth::attempt()`

Just change your `Auth::attempt` code to this, and the rest of your code will work (i.e. do not reassign the `$user` variable again);

```
Auth::attempt(array(
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password
));
```

Comment: Thanks - I also had to change the order of the process as just removing $user from Auth didn't work on its own. Thanks for explaining it.